# Cardinality of set of powers and roots of an element in a group $G$

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory

For a finite group $G$ and $a \in G$, we define

$${\rm Pow}(a) := \left\{b \in G : b \in <a> \text{ or } a \in <b> \right\}.$$

is it possible to explicitly count the cardinality of this set for some classes of finite groups?

Also, is there any name for this set in the literature?

Kindly share your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: The notation is quite confusing. It first seems you fix some choice of root function (i.e. fix one arbitrary partial function $a\mapsto a^{1/k}$). But I guess you don't want $\mathrm{Pow}(a)$ to depend on any choice. Thus you should define $\mathrm{Pow}^-(a)=\{b:a\in\langle b\rangle\}$ and then $\mathrm{Pow}(a)=\mathrm{Pow}^-(a)\cup\langle a\rangle$. Probably, it would be more natural to count the cardinal of $\mathrm{Pow}^-(a)$ itself (since the cardinal $n$ of $\langle a\rangle$ is the order of $a$ and the cardinal of $\mathrm{Pow}^-(a)\cap\langle a\rangle$ is $\varphi(n)$).

Comment: @YCor Thank you. This way the definition of Pow(a) is easy to understand. Also, how to show that $\mathrm{Pow}^-(a)\cap\langle a\rangle$ is equal to $\phi(n)$ and What is n here? Please explain. Thanks again.

Comment: I think it should not be to difficult to study this on finite abelian groups using their classification. I suggest to first look at cyclic p-groups, then finite abelian p-groups and then finite abelian groups.

Comment: @YCor are you taking n as the order of a?

Comment: @GA316 yes (this was already explicit in my previous comment)

Comment: @YCor Thank you. now I understood. We need the cardinality of $\rm{Pow}^{-}(a) \backslash \langle a \rangle $ to calculate the cardinality of $\rm{Pow}(a) = (\rm{Pow}^{-}(a) \backslash \langle a \rangle) \sqcup \langle a\rangle $. What could be the cardinality of $\rm{Pow}^{-}(a) \backslash \langle a \rangle$? Thank you.